# Probability Dependent

Tags: probability, self-study, joint-distribution

Okay so for the following question (d), why is the probabily calculated by P(man)+P(hip replacement)-P(man and hip replacement)=110/200+80/200-57/110 rather than 110/200+80/200-57/200. Isn't the total population 200 so the denominator of the last term needs to be 200 as well (I am just imagining a Venn Diagram when answering this question)? Thanks! 
[image]

Comment: How many people are either men and/or have had a hip replacement?  How many people are there total?

Comment: I'm still confused as to why you divide by the total number of men rather than the total population. Cause lets say you imagine a Venn diagram. You are subtracting the overlapping sections of men and hip replacement from the total population of men OR hip replacement, which is 200? Thanks for any input !

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition is correct. 
There are several ways to approach this.

- You can sum the different cases: P(hip & man) + P(hip & woman) + P(knee & man) = (57+23+53)/200
- You can take out the omitted case: 1-P(knee & woman) = 1-67/200
- You can sum on the marginals and subtract the double count, which is what you had proposed: P(hip) + P(man) - P(hip & man) = (80+110-57)/200

In any of these cases, the probabilities are unconditional, so we divide by the total population: 200.

Comment: Thanks Roland, the reason I asked is cause my stats prof said it was 110/200+80/200-57/110 . I have no idea why she said that and it wasn't the first answer  came up with. I did what you said.

Comment: Either your professor misspoke or you misunderstood. 200 is correct